# How to connect a load combinator to a load amplifier for load cells

Tags: load-cell

I would like to link 4 load cells sensors to an arduino. I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide). I am using [this load combinator](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13878?_ga=1.234217566.1928427279.1466468988)

[image]

and I need to connect it to [this load amplifier](http://www.dx.com/p/maitech-03100574-hx711-weighing-sensor-module-pressure-sensor-module-green-308904#.V9JEOk19600)

[image]

The combinator has E+ E- A- A+ SLD outputs
The amplifier has E+ E- A- A+ B- B+

How do I connect the 2 boards?

Comment: Also, this load combinator switches the Red (positive) and White (signal) cables of all the gauge sensors. Ridiculous Sparkfun mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect:

Amplifier
........ Combinator

E+ ... Red
E- .... Black
A- .... White
A+ ... Green

[image]

[**HX711 data sheet**](http://www.elecrow.com/download/hx711_english.pdf)

**___________________________**

**Because:**

On [**this Sparkfun page**](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/SparkFun%20Load%20Sensor%20Combinator%20v11.pdf) you will find the diagram below. At upper right I've added a red rectangle to highlight the relationshp between the amplifier connector labels and the Sparkfun colour-based connection names.

Your [**Maitek HX711 amplifier**](http://www.dx.com/p/maitech-03100574-hx711-weighing-sensor-module-pressure-sensor-module-green-308904#.V9Jlj5h95aR) is similar in functionality to the
[**Sparkfun HX711 amplifier**](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide) EXCEPT that your version uses both amplifiers/ channels in the HX711 and sparkfun only use one.

[image]

---

[**HX711 surprisingly good data sheet**](http://www.elecrow.com/download/hx711_english.pdf)  and [demo library and code](http://www.elecrow.com/download/hx711.zip) - zip file - I have not opened it.

From Elecrow [**here**](http://www.elecrow.com/weight-sensor-amplifier-hx711-p-715.html)

Lots of relevant information [**here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=hx711&oq=hx711&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.1605.3058.0.3308.6.6.0.0.0.0.257.1391.2-6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..0.5.1160.0..35i39k1j0i131k1.4tFuSFKPNMA) and [**here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=hx711&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOh-rH6IHPAhWMHJQKHQX5CZkQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=717)

[HX711 on Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=226314.0)

---

Here is one example of the HX711's use:

[image]

Note the two input channels - only one shown in use.
If a second bridge was used it could share the V_AVDD and ground leads (E+ / E- = excitation +/-)

[From this better-detailed than many seller's page](http://www.sunrom.com/p/loadcell-sensor-24-bit-adc-hx711)

---

GITHUB Arduino library - [An Arduino library to interface the Avia Semiconductor HX711 24-Bit Analog-to-Digital Converter {ADC} for Weight Scales.](https://github.com/bogde/HX711)

[Instructaaaaaaaaaaables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-your-weighing-scale-hack-using-arduino/)

[50 assembled boards](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/10PCS-Hx711-module-weighing-sensor-ad-module-mcu-diy/512100_910591619.html) for $US0.70 each !!!!

Comment: Could you please help me with a similar problem? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365865/how-to-connect-bathroom-scale-arduinohx711spark-load-connector